# What is the connection between <?php wp_head() ?> and CSS media queries in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to add a separate .css for the WP site display on smartphones. However, the mobile.css file cannot be load when I tested it on a real server. Why? At least the only one thing I found out is, when I include the `wp_head();` in the head tags, the desktop style.css is loading properly but the mobile.css is not; when I delete `wp_head`, the desktop one is not working but the mobile.css works!

That sounds irrational! But it is happening. Why? Below is the code I am using in header.php. The title and script tags are left out.

```
<head>

  <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <meta http-equiv="cleartype" content="on">
  <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="True">
  <meta name="MobileOptimized" content="320"> 
  <link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
  <link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/> 
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mobile.css" media="only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)" />

  <title>...</title>
  <script>...</script>  
  <?php wp_head(); ?> 
</head>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think style.css is already Loaded via functions.php, find the code in functions.php and remove that. 
the code is like

```
 function WordPress_resources() {   
    wp_enqueue_style('style', get_stylesheet_uri());    
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'WordPress_resources');
```

remove device in (max-device-width: 480px) ----> to (max-width: 480px)

You need to add template directory,

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/style.css"/> 
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/mobile.css" media="only screen and (max-width: 480px)" />
```

Comment: You can [*edit*](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/31636393/edit) your old answer if you want to improve it. Don't post a new answer.

Comment: tried again, not really solving it yet but thank you

Comment: At Browser View Source Code, Check the Head element. check the style sheet attachments.